# how to inject a module within another module by zend framework 2?

Tags: php, design-patterns, module, zend-framework2

I am trying to understand how to create two simple indipendent modules by zf2 where some information/features of the module A are called by the module B.

For instance:

Module A handles the pages of a site
Module B handles the languages available at the site

Module A is connected to a data table where the fields are: [id, title, content, language_id]
Module B is connected to a data table where the fields are: [id, language]

Module A [language_id] is not mandatory.

Module A needs to get the list of the languages from the Module B. 
Module B has not any othe module dependence

I would like to disable the Module B without throwning an exception.
I would like to enable the Module B and see the language selector within the Module A form.

is this possible? thanks

Comment: If module B handles the languages, if you disabled module B what would you want to see instead of the language selector in the form?

Comment: Hi Tim, it's simple. That feature will be no more available and the language information in the Module A will be no more visible. I would like to disable that feature

Comment: @Marius.C can you show me a sample? I would like to add the Module B without change anything in the Module A. Module A intercept the presence of the Module B and activate the new feature. Is it too complicated to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Add a config var in your Module_B in `config/module.config.php`

`"my_module" => array("have_lang_module" => true)`

then in module_A you can check that:

`$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
if (isset($config['my_module']['have_lang_module'])) {...}`

I'm not an expert but I don't see why this would not work. Basically configurations files
are loaded and merged and available to all modules.

Comment: Hi Marius, in this way you have to change the code. What I want to achieve is create an automatic "injection of features" in a module by other modules.